# Rxjs switchMap not calling the function passed through it

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using `Subject` observable from `rxjs`. I've two methods that I called from my component.

1. Search

```typescript
search(terms: Observable<string>) {
  return terms.pipe(
    debounceTime(400),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(term => {
      this.numberOfItems = API_INFO.PER_PAGE_ITEMS;
      return this.getPosts(term)
    })
  );
}
```

2. Loadmore

```typescript
loadmore(terms: Observable<string>, pageNumber) {
  this.numberOfItems = API_INFO.PER_PAGE_ITEMS * pageNumber;
  return terms.pipe(
    debounceTime(0),
    switchMap((term: string) => this.getPosts(term))
  )
}
```

component subscription code

```typescript
this.homeService.search(this.searchLocation$)
      .subscribe((data)=>this.handleSuccess(data),(err)=>this.handleError(err))
```

The issue is `search` works fine while `loadmore` doesn't although they both have the same code

PS: I'm using the same subscription model for both of the observable

Comment: Are you using async pipe to subscribe to observable for loadmore function?

Comment: question updated

Comment: I do not have clear the basics of the logic you are implementing. When does `terms` (i,e. this.searchLocation$)  emit? Why do you pass it in as parameters in functions such as `search` and `loadmore`? When are `search` and `loadmore` called?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **merge** to get data from both observable, the one coming from search and the one coming from load more event

loadmore event can be a scroll event or a button click event

```
<button #loadmore>Button</button>
```

...

```
@ViewChild('loadmore', { static: true }) button: ElementRef;
let loadmore$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click');

...

merge(this.homeService.search(this.searchLocation$),
   this.homeService.loadmore(this.loadmore$, pageNumber))
.pipe(
  distinct()
).subscribe(
  (data)=>this.handleSuccess(data),
  (err)=>this.handleError(err)
)
```

Comment: I guess my question is misleading. What I'm trying to ask is the `swictchMap` in search function works fine while in `loadmore` doesn't. What might be the issue here